# Trouble with mx record and mailbox

Tags: email, postfix, mail

I have a machine running on Internet with valid IP address 216.x.x.x. I have installed postfix on it. I have also purchased a domain, let's say example.com for it from godaddy.

I have a problem in regard to my mx record, which causes some confusion for me.

In the GoDaddy,

I have the A record as :

@ 216.x.x.x

and the MX record as:

@ example.com

I see people saying you need to add 'mail' as an A record and MX record. Like this

A record: mail mail.example.com
MX record: mail mail.example.com

But I am running the postfix on port 25 on example.com and I do not have any mail.example.com.

So the question is if my current setting correct or not, if not why is not right and why I need to add the mail.example.com to my MX record and why @ 216.x.x.x does not work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no necessity that an `MX` record should begin with `mail.`. As per your settings

```
dig mx example.com
```

should give

```
example.com. some_ttl IN      MX    some_priority  example.com.
```

and

```
dig example.com
```

should give

```
example.com.   some_ttl IN  A   216.x.x.x
```

for emails from outside world to reach you. Hope that helps.